# Disabling a MAX487 in an orderly fashion

Tags: pcb-design, uart, serial

I have a custom Arduino design with an MAX487 for serial communication. I'm currently "disabling" it for programming of the AVR by disconnecting the GND of the MAX487, but it was suggested that this is the wrong way. I received a suggestion that i should use a pull-up resistor on RE/DE but can't find any documentation about this. Can someone shed some light on the proper way to go about this please?

If the MAX487 is connected to the TX/RX lines of the AVR, it interferes with programming of the AVR even if the MAX487 is not connected to anything via its A/B lines.

Comment: You can insert a 1..2 kohm resistor between the RX output of the MAX487 and the rest of the circuit. This way the programmer wins if connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no documentation other than the datasheet which tells you how the chip works.

It is up to you and your application to use the chip so that it works in your application.

The problem is that if you simply keep MAX487 RE pin low, the MAX487 RO is an output and you can't program the AVR because you can't have two outputs, the MAX487 and programming cable outputs, connected together and driving the AVR RXD input simultaneously.

To disable the MAX487 RO data output from driving the AVR RXD data input, the MAX487 RE receiver output enable pin must be high.

So in bootloader mode, make sure that the RE pin is pulled up by a resistor or set high by the bootloader.

And when running normally, set the RE pin low to receive data.

The same (related or unrelated) problem may be with the transmit side too. If it does not matter if the AVR TXD drives the RS-485 bus during programming, then it does not matter in which state the DE driver enable pin is. But if it does matter, you may choose to set DE low or pull it low with a resistor to set a default state to ďisable transmitting, and only when AVR is running normally and wants to transmit, then set DE high.

On many occasions DE and RE are wired together so depending on your connections it is possible that you can either switch between RS-485 driver to drive the bus and RS-485 receiver to drive output to AVR.